# Not sure how this code works to get the tree diameter

Tags: python, recursion, tree, depth-first-search

I am not sure how this solution works.

Given a binary tree, find the length of its diameter. The diameter of a tree is the number of nodes on the longest path between any two leaf nodes. The diameter of a tree may or may not pass through the root.

Note: You can always assume that there are at least two leaf nodes in the given tree.

```
class TreeNode:
  def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
    self.val = val
    self.left = left
    self.right = right


class TreeDiameter:

  def __init__(self):
    self.treeDiameter = 0

  def find_diameter(self, root):
    self.calculate_height(root)
    return self.treeDiameter

  def calculate_height(self, currentNode):
    if currentNode is None:
      return 0

    leftTreeHeight = self.calculate_height(currentNode.left)
    rightTreeHeight = self.calculate_height(currentNode.right)

    # if the current node doesn't have a left or right subtree, we can't have
    # a path passing through it, since we need a leaf node on each side
    if leftTreeHeight is not None and rightTreeHeight is not None:

      # diameter at the current node will be equal to the height of left subtree +
      # the height of right sub-trees + '1' for the current node
      diameter = leftTreeHeight + rightTreeHeight + 1

      # update the global tree diameter
      self.treeDiameter = max(self.treeDiameter, diameter)

    # height of the current node will be equal to the maximum of the heights of
    # left or right subtrees plus '1' for the current node
    return max(leftTreeHeight, rightTreeHeight) + 1


def main():
  treeDiameter = TreeDiameter()
  root = TreeNode(1)
  root.left = TreeNode(2)
  root.right = TreeNode(3)
  root.left.left = TreeNode(4)
  root.right.left = TreeNode(5)
  root.right.right = TreeNode(6)
  print("Tree Diameter: " + str(treeDiameter.find_diameter(root)))
  root.left.left = None
  root.right.left.left = TreeNode(7)
  root.right.left.right = TreeNode(8)
  root.right.right.left = TreeNode(9)
  root.right.left.right.left = TreeNode(10)
  root.right.right.left.left = TreeNode(11)
  print("Tree Diameter: " + str(treeDiameter.find_diameter(root)))


main()
```

My first thought would have been to add 1 each time I see a left node and 1 each time I see a right node, but from the code above I see that the solution just assigns the recursive call to `leftTreeHeight` and `rightTreeHeight`. Then we check if we have leaf nodes on each left and right side because if we did not then we wouldn't be able to add anything because of the definition of tree diameter.

From here what I see is that maybe once we start popping off the stack is how we are updating our values but I am having difficulty wrapping my head around this. I debugged this code to see how it is working but it's hard to follow for me.

Answer (score 0):

For each node, you can compute a "node-local" diameter, which is just the longest distance from up from one leaf, through the node, and back down to another leaf. The diameter of the tree is the maximum of all node-local diameters.

Essentially, `calculate_height` calculates the node-local diameter of each node in a bottom-up fashion, so that all node-local diameters are found as a side effect of computing the height of a tree.

---

The term "diameter" comes from the fact that you can choose any node in a tree to be "the" root, so that a tree with diameter `d` can be re-interpreted as a tree whose longest up-down path through the root is the same as the diameter, making the root somewhat analogous to the "center" of the tree (though the root does not need to be the same distance to the two leaves in question).

Answer (score 0):

That code works but I think the implementation is not right. Because:

```
if currentNode is None:
      return 0
```

this code says if the node is "null", it is height is 0. Ok! what about the height of a single node. That is 0, too. Let's say you did recursive calls and reach the leaf of the tree:

[image]

when you reach "null", it will return -1. when you reach node8, it will ask its left and right "What is your height" and they will return `(-1)+(-1)=-2`.
We know that height of a single node is 0, so height of node8 will be 0. Currently node8 receive `-2` from his call. To make math work, we say

```
height_node8=(-1)+(-1) + 2
```

So this statement

```
  ` diameter = leftTreeHeight + rightTreeHeight + 1  `
```

should be

```
  diameter = leftTreeHeight + rightTreeHeight + 2
```

and

```
  if currentNode is None:
      return -1
```

I hope that makes sense: